# Aligning elements in HTML

Tags: html, css

So I have a problem regarding this piece of html code:

```html
<fieldset style="margin-left: 20px;">
       <legend><em>Credit Holder Information</em></legend>
           <b>Credit card:</b><br>
        <select name="credit card" style="background-color: gainsboro; border-radius: 6px;">
            <option> Visa </option>
            <option> MasterCard </option>
            <option> AMEX </option>
            <option> Discover </option>
         </select>
       <label for="num" class="number" style="white-space: normal;"><b>Number:</b></label>
       <input type="number" name="num"/>
       <label for="expdate" class="number"><b>Expiration date:</b></label>
       <select style="width: 100px; background-color: gainsboro; border-radius: 6px;">
            <option></option>
            <option> January </option>
            <option> Feburary</option>
            <option> March</option>
            <option> April</option>
            <option> May</option>
            <option> June</option>
            <option> July</option>
            <option> August</option>
            <option> September</option>
            <option> October</option>
            <option> November</option>
            <option> December</option>
        </select>
        <input type="number" min="1900" name="expdate" style="width: 50px; background-color: gainsboro; border-radius: 6px;"/>
```

The problem is that I want the output of `Number:` and `Expiration date:` *to be on top of* `<input type="number"/>` and `<select>` tags, respectively . But I got this output:
[First output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPI7P.png). And also, using `<br>` with `Number:` and `Expiration date:` causes this: [Output after using line break](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D99HP.png)

I don't know how to workaround this and will want a quick fix that I can integrate into the code easily

**NB**

1. I don't want to use an external style sheet so I used inline styling for the parts that required it.
2. I don't want to use `position: absolute` or anything related to `position` as it made my code whacky and will require me to use an external style sheet, which I don't want to use and will also take a considerable amount of time to structure everything properly, which I also don't have at the moment as this is an assignment.
3. I tried a variety of methods but they will require me to rewrite the whole code from scratch, which I can't do because of the time constraint
4. I'm an absolute beginner at this, so I don't really know a lot about HTML and CSS and would appreciate for answers or contributions to be clear and specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really hope I understood this right. Without using any positioning you'll have to rearrange the elements in the html to get the flow you want. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```html
<fieldset style="margin-left: 20px;">
  <legend><em>Credit Holder Information</em></legend>
  <b>Credit card:</b><br>
  <select name="credit card" style="background-color: gainsboro; border-radius: 6px;">
    <option> Visa </option>
    <option> MasterCard </option>
    <option> AMEX </option>
    <option> Discover </option>
  </select>
  <input type="number" name="num" />
  <select style="width: 100px; background-color: gainsboro; border-radius: 6px;">
    <option></option>
    <option> January </option>
    <option> Feburary</option>
    <option> March</option>
    <option> April</option>
    <option> May</option>
    <option> June</option>
    <option> July</option>
    <option> August</option>
    <option> September</option>
    <option> October</option>
    <option> November</option>
    <option> December</option>
  </select>
  <input type="number" min="1900" name="expdate" style="width: 50px; background-color: gainsboro; border-radius: 6px;" />
  <br>
  <label for="num" class="number" style="white-space: normal; margin-left: 100px"><b>Number:</b></label>
  <label for="expdate" class="number" style="margin-left: 85px"><b>Expiration date:</b></label>
```

Comment: Exactly!! But when i ran it it came under instead of on top.

Comment: Great. Don’t forget to hit answer.